# Language specific resource file is changing in between the operations in wpf

Tags: wpf, localization

We have implemented localisation in our WPF app. While loading the application we are setting culture info and based on that application is loading resource files. It is working as expected but after doing some operations in UI, resource file values are changing to English by default and again after some operations it is converting to the original language specified. These are changing alternatively based on some operations

Below is the code we have utilised

```
public partial class App : WindowsApplication
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
                var CurrentLanguage = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CurrentLanguage;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CurrentLanguage;
        }

}
```

[resources we are using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKJIE.png)